# digitally sign xml using xml-crypto in nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml, xml-crypto

I am using xml-crypto version 6 to digitally sign xml in nodejs. But the package automatically add `Id="_0"` and `URI="#_0"` attribute to the elements being signed.

Can anyone one help how to disable the addition of attributes.

I am trying to digitally sign a xml code using `pem` file with the `xml-crypto` package in nodejs.
It successfully sign the package and verify the xml also. But it automatically add the attributes, that is not required in the next flow.